# How to change Text property with ICommand C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I make a simple weather app. And now i want to change it.
I want to implement a command to a button, and when is pressed, a TextBlock will update with weather info but i can't acces property of TextBlock.

Here is the Command class from Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace RemakeWindowsWeather.Models
{
    public class Command : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod;
        Action<object> executeMethod;


        public Command(Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod, Action<object> executeMethod)
        {
            this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
            this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecuteMethod(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            executeMethod(parameter);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class from ViewModels where i want to change the property of TextBlock:

```
using RemakeWindowsWeather.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RemakeWindowsWeather.ViewModels
{
    public class CommandViewModel 
    {
        Command ShowWeather { get; set; }

        public CommandViewModel()
        {
            ShowWeather = new Command(canExecuteMethod, executeMethod);
        }


        private bool canExecuteMethod(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        private async void executeMethod(object parameter)
        {
            var pos = await LocationManager.GetLocation();

            var lat = pos.Coordinate.Latitude;
            var lon = pos.Coordinate.Longitude;

            var weather = await WeatherProxyMap.GetWeather(lon, lat);

            //HERE.. not working
            WeatherCondition.Text = weather.main.temp + " " + weather.name;

        }



    }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="RemakeWindowsWeather.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:RemakeWindowsWeather"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="MyPage">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="30"
                Width="120"
                Click="Button_Click" 
                Content="Get Weather"/>
        <TextBlock Name="WeatherCondition" 
                   Margin="0,20,0,20"/>
        <TextBox Name="CitySearch"
                 PlaceholderText="Search for weather.."
                 Margin="0,20,0,20"/>
        <Button Width="120"
                Height="30"
                Click="Button_Click_1"
                Content="Get Weather"/>
        <TextBlock Name="CityNameTxtBlock"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Am I missing something here?  What is your question?

Comment: The command should not be able to access any of your view elements. Instead the command should set a Property on your (view)model which the view is bound to.

Comment: WeatherCondition.Text = weather.main.temp + " " + weather.name;

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your command from the viewmodel in xaml, instead using event handlers in the view.

```
<Button Width="120"
    Height="30"
    Command="{Binding ShowWeather}"
    Content="Get Weather"/>
```

Also the command should be public and you need a text property

```
public Command ShowWeather { get; set; }

public string WeatherText { get; set; }
```

Then you need to bind the text from the viewmodel in the view.

```
<TextBlock Name="WeatherCondition" Margin="0,20,0,20" Text="{Binding WeatherText}"/>
```

also you would need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) in the viewmodel and call it when you modify the text.

```
WeatherText= weather.main.temp + " " + weather.name;
this.RaisePropertyChanged("WeatherText");
```

This pretty much basic MVVM which you can read about from [here](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html).